# Make unity play high frequency audio exact like the original wav file for hearing test

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, frequency

I am making a unity hearing test, I already manage to do all the code to play the audios, the problem is that unity is changing the way the files are played, for eg one of the files is 18000 Hz, when I open the file and play out of unity it is imposible to me hear anything, but if I play in unity I can hear it very clearly, what can be messing with the audio? 
I am keeping the original audio sample rate and my audio sourcer is with default settings, here is the code to play the audio:

```
void PlayAudio(AudioClip auc) {
    aus.PlayOneShot(auc, 1);

}`
```

here is the audio source:
[image: here is the image]

as you can see normal settings

[image: here is the project audio setting]

Thanks for hearing me

Comment: Have you checked the import settings for the audio? You may want to use an external library if Unitys own importing and replaying system is not sufficient to your requirements.

Comment: yes, it is set to keep the sample rate, I tried all the other setting there and got some improvement but nothing solved the problem

Comment: I will make some search into external libraries that can work with unity, but am still hoping it is only a unity settings problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and used this [script](https://forum.unity.com/threads/onaudiofilterread-question.170273/#post-1164846) for simple sinewave generation

For audio files I chose [FMOD](https://www.fmod.com/resources/documentation-unity)

Comment: Dude I love you for real, I was almost giving up, Thanks a lot